# skip_blank_lines is not working with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
test_scores = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1, 2, '', 4, 5], 
'first_name' : ['Sachin', 'Dravid', '', 'Virat', 'Yuvraj'],
'scores' : [150, 210, '', 125, 75],
'state' : ['Mumbai', 'Karnataka','', 'Delhi', 'Punjab']})

test_scores.to_csv("test_scores.csv", sep = ',', header = True, index = False)

skip = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = 'test_scores.csv', sep = ',', header = 0, skip_blank_lines = True)

skip
```

**I wanted to remove the blank lines the row with NaN values.
But even after applying skip_blank_lines = True, the NaN values are not skipped or removed.**

Comment: rows having **NaN** as values are not considered blank.

Comment: `NaN- Not a Number` is not blank. It special floating-point value. It even have a dataType `float`. You need to `drop` If you want to remove them

Comment: So then in what case can I use skip_blank_lines=True parameter?

Comment: @Curious in case you have blank lines i.e. nothing at all on the line (no characters)

Comment: @mozway i want to understand that if skip_blank_lines is applied for removing the NaN then why isnt it doing its task? And why do we need to use dropna(how = any) in its place? I did created another .csv file and left a complete line blank between the records. Then also it didnt work.

Comment: Because a line with commas is not **blank**, try to insert **blank** lines (i.e. nothing between newlines) and you will see the difference

Answer (score 1):

Your line is not **blank**, it has all empty values. You need to use [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
skip = (pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='test_scores.csv', sep=',', header=0,
                    skip_blank_lines=True, # not needed here
                    )
          .dropna(how='all')
       )
```

output:

```
    id first_name  scores      state
0  1.0     Sachin   150.0     Mumbai
1  2.0     Dravid   210.0  Karnataka
3  4.0      Virat   125.0      Delhi
4  5.0     Yuvraj    75.0     Punjab
```

Comment: Thank you mozway. Your suggestion worked.