# skip_blank_lines not skipping the NaN lines

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parameters

Which blank lines does this parameter skip_blank_lines remove?
I have seen few example by searching the google.
According to the definition it is supposed to remove a complete line or rows filled with NaN.
But in my case it isn't removing the line of NaNs.

I am confused about the usage of this parameter.

Even when I am creating a new .csv file, then I am purposefully leaving an entire line blank between the records.
And yet when I read it with pd.read_csv("filename.csv", skip_blank_lines = True), I am still getting the output of lines filled with NaN.

Please suggest a better solution.

```
skip3 = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = 'height.csv', header = 0, skip_blank_lines = True)
skip3
```

CSV File

[image: Created a .csv file with blank records]

GETTING OUTPUT AS THIS:-

```
id  name    height
0   1.0 Akshay  185.0
1   2.0 Salman  170.0
2   NaN NaN NaN
3   4.0 John    180.0
4   5.0 Ranbir  175.0
```

PLEASE HELP TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM.

Comment: please do not ask twice the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74208522/skip-blank-lines-is-not-working-with-pandas)

Comment: @Curious If there is something insufficient about the answer on your previous post, then it's fine to ask a new question, but be sure to make it clear that this is a followup to your previous question and clarify what problem you have that isn't addressed by the answer.

Comment: But the problem is not resolved.

Comment: i want to understand that if skip_blank_lines is applied for removing the NaN then why isnt it doing its task? And why do we need to use dropna(how = any) in its place?

Comment: @Curious I see. I would recommend that you ask a new question that includes a link to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74208522/2476977) for context and makes it very clear that what you're interested is **not** finding a way to read the csv without getting NaN's (since you already have one), but rather understanding how the `skip_blank_lines` option is supposed to work.

Comment: @Curious I think the misunderstanding is happening for people who quickly skimmed your question, saw that your explanatory text ended with "please suggest a better solution", and therefore concluded that the main thing you're after with this question is a way to get the result that you expected, even if that result is not necessarily obtained using the `read_csv` command alone.

Comment: @Curious I also think that there is a difference between saying "I am confused about the usage of this parameter" (which merely explains why you're having trouble) and saying "please explain how this parameter is supposed to be used".

Comment: @Curious You could also try making these clarifying changes to your current post, but questions that are closed on this cite have the unfortunate tendency to stay closed even when they ought to be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code after loading the dataframe to remove al the NaN values:

```
# Drop the rows where at least one element is missing.
df.dropna()
```